# Get an element's ID and compare it to a string OR another ID

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How can I get the ID of an element and compare it to a string OR another id ?

What I would like to do exactly is make a condition that would get the element's ID and compare it to a certain string or another element's ID.

I have this piece of code right now to compare my id to another id (which obviously doesn't work):

```
function Something(elemid)
{
 if(elemid == document.getElementById('myid').id)
   {
    ...
   }
}
```

Or this piece of code to compare to a string (doesn't work either):

```
if(elemid == "mystring")
{
...
}
```

This is a simple problem, but still, I can't seem to find anything around here or even on other websites that would be what I am searching for.
**I can't use any JQuery whatsoever, so any Javascript only anwser would be really appreciated.**

Comment: `document.getElementById('myid').id` is somewhat unnecessary because it will give `myid` always

Comment: Why doesn' the second piece of code work?

Comment: What's the value of `elemid`? Are you sure it has the value it's supposed to have?

Comment: @orique: Yes, it has the value that it is supposed to have (verified troughout my function execution).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 if(elemid = document.getElementById('myid').id)
   {
    ...
   }
```

You need to compare it using `==`.  A single `=` is assign.

Also `document.getElementById('myid').id` is completely useless.  You are specifying the `id` directly and then attempt to return it.

As a simple test to show you how to compare an element.

```
<input type="text" id="hello" class="test" />

var element = document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0].id;

if (element === "hello") {
   alert("Working"); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ckJP9/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Darren Davies !
The single = was a typo, sorry about that ! I corrected it on my first post.

Also:
_Also document.getElementById('myid').id is completely useless. You are specifying the id directly and then attempt to return it._

By this, do you mean that `document.getElementById('myid') == elemid` would also work ?

Comment: he's saying that it's equivalent to `myid == elemid`

Answer (score 1):

How are you calling the function from jsp?

This code works for me:

```
function getValue(elementId)
{
  //comparing
  if(document.getElementById("myHeader").id == elementId)
  {
    alert('It Works!');
  }
}
```

and in the jsp

`<h1 id="myHeader" onclick="getValue('myHeader')">Click me!</h1>`